# Traer y pintar una imagen tipo BLOB react nodejs

Tags: javascript, sql, nodejs, reactjs, blob

tengo una imagen guardada en sql alla seria varbinary(MAX), pero en mi nodejs con ORM es BLOB, realizo una consulta a la bd y me trae todos los datos correctos menos la imagen la cual llega como undefined.
[image: Esta seria mi base de datos]

datos
[image: aqui podemos ver lo que tiene almacenado]

entonces tengo estas funciones

```
async function generateMensaje(tipoInteresado){
    const mensajes = await ListMensaje(serviceLocator);
    var mensaje,imagen, retorno;
    mensajes.forEach(element => {
    console.log("numero ---> ",element.IdMensaje);    
    tipoInteresado==element.TipoInteresado?mensaje=element.TipoMensaje:console.log("tipoInteresado ", element.TipoInteresado, " tipo de dato -> ",element.TipoInteresado.type);
    element.ImagenTemplate?imagen=ImagenTemplate:console.log("imagen.> ",element.ImagenTemplate);
    // console.log("===================",imagen ,"------------" );
    });
    retorno = mensaje+" ---> "+imagen;
    // console.log(" ---> ", retorno);
    return  retorno;
}
```

esta me trae los datos de bd pero me trae imagen como indefinido y todos aparecen como type indefinido tambien.

```
numero --->  1
imagen.>  undefined
numero --->  2
tipoInteresado  Cliente Industrial  tipo de dato ->  undefined
imagen.>  undefined
numero --->  3
tipoInteresado  Ejecutivo  tipo de dato ->  undefined
imagen.>  undefined
numero --->  4
tipoInteresado  Interno  tipo de dato ->  undefined
imagen.>  undefined
numero --->  5
imagen.>  undefined
numero --->  6
tipoInteresado  Cliente Industrial  tipo de dato ->  undefined
imagen.>  undefined
numero --->  7
tipoInteresado  Ejecutivo  tipo de dato ->  undefined
imagen.>  undefined
numero --->  8
tipoInteresado  Interno  tipo de dato ->  undefined
imagen.>  undefined
correoElectronico ---> undefined <----- imprime
numero --->  1
imagen.>  undefined
numero --->  2
tipoInteresado  Cliente Industrial  tipo de dato ->  undefined
imagen.>  undefined
numero --->  3
tipoInteresado  Ejecutivo  tipo de dato ->  undefined
imagen.>  undefined
numero --->  4
tipoInteresado  Interno  tipo de dato ->  undefined
imagen.>  undefined
numero --->  5
imagen.>  undefined
numero --->  6
tipoInteresado  Cliente Industrial  tipo de dato ->  undefined
imagen.>  undefined
numero --->  7
tipoInteresado  Ejecutivo  tipo de dato ->  undefined
imagen.>  undefined
numero --->  8
tipoInteresado  Interno  tipo de dato ->  undefined
imagen.>  undefined
correoElectronico ---> undefined <----- imprime
```

este es ListMensaje

```
'use strict';

module.exports = ({ mensajeRepository }) => {
  return mensajeRepository.find();
};
```

en el controloller tengo

```
  async sendEmail(request, h){

    emailService.generateMensaje();
    
    return h.response().code(200);
  },
```

estoy empleando react y llamo de esta forma en panlla, la idea es mandar un correo con los datos, lo ideal es poder pintar la imagen en este formato html para poder enviarla por correo.
${mensaje} es la variable que me llega del bd

```
//Configure E-Mail Sending
async function sendEmail(subject, text, attachments, addressee, type) {
    var mailOptions;
    switch (type){
        case "Interesado":
        let mensaje = await generateMensaje("Cliente");
        console.log(mensaje , "<----- imprime")
            mailOptions = {
                from: environment.SMTP.USER,
                to: addressee,
                subject: subject,
                text: text,
                html: 
                `<p style="font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri,sans-serif;margin:0;">
                    Buenas tardes,
                </p>
                <p>${mensaje}</p>
                <p/>
                <p style="font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri,sans-serif;margin:0;">
                    En la siguiente ruta se puede consultar las afectaciones de servicio a los clientes y el programa semanal de consignaciones aprobadas para la siguiente Semana.
                </p>
                <p/>
                <a href="sAfectados" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" data-auth="NotApplicable" data-linkindex="0" style="color: rgb(133, 181, 255) !important;" data-ogsc="" id="LPlnk590768">https:ectados</a>`
                ,
                attachments: attachments
            };
            break;
```

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Qué versión de NodeJS y React estás usando?

Comment: hola, node 16.16.0 y react 18.2.0